# How to know to post what where

Tags: support

So i've been trying to post a question on one of the exchanges. Its related to educational programming classes. Although it keeps getting moved around and now its closed. So, how do i know where to post it? I see other questions similar to mine that have stayed open, i just don't get it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is *about* programming, ie the process of programming, problems encountered while programming, etc, then it goes on stackoverflow.

Otherwise we don't really have a site for your question, although there is a proposal for one here:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2529/computer-science-education

However, I'm not sure that even that would fit into the stack exchange model of Q&A sites.

Your question,

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57352/college-courses-through-distance-learning-closed

Is really too localized - it applies to one person, at one point in time, and even if one generalizes the answers they will be out of date very quickly.

If you wanted to have even a small chance of making this question viable on the stack exchange network, you'd have to simplify it, and generalize it.

"What accredited schools offer distance learning classes in CS?"

This would provide a list of schools that might have what you need, and while you'd still have to do some footwork to find out which ones happen to have exactly what you need at this point in time, it is a tiny little bit less likely to be closed.

Although it's still too localized and somewhat subjective.

I think you'll have to look for other resources to get this question answered - surely your school's guidance counselors can give you pointers to schools that have distance learning in your field, or at least how to find such schools.

Comment: I miss Pollyanna.

Comment: Its more of where can i find these programming classes i need online. It is related to the computer science major. I have seen other people post about it before as well as other "off-topic" posts that never get closed.

Comment: @balpha Yeah, I still have mixed feelings about leaving her behind like stale waffles.

Comment: @Matt I expanded my answer to address your specific question.

Comment: @Admin Davis - yea ok. Thats one thing i hate about the stack exchange is that you know someone will have an answer, someone has done it before yet you can't ask it because it doesn't follow the rules. Oh well, ill try hackernews. Thanks though.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, there's a constant tension between supporting *"timeless questions"* vs supporting *"questions our experts can answer."*  We tend to shy away from the latter very strongly, because early on we had a spate of, "What is the best lunch for programmers?" type questions.  Sure, there are a lot of questions we *can* answer, but by keeping a laser sharp focus on questions that are timeless, and objective we avoid becoming like yahoo answers (anything and everything) and we have a strong signal to noise ratio, which keeps the experts around for real programming problems.